# How to create a table with header using append jquery function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, append, appendchild

I have created a table and getting data but i want header in that table.Kindly help me out.

My code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $(function () {
            $("#<%=txtCu.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Webservice.asmx/GetCus") %>',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        mustMatch: true,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('^')[0],
                                    val: item.split('^')[1]
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {

                        },
                        failure: function (response) {

                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#<%=hdnCr.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
                    if (i.item.val == "No Records Found") {
                        $("#<%=hdnCr.ClientID %>").val(-1);
                        document.getElementById('<%=txtCu.ClientID%>').value = "";
                        return false;
                    }
                    checkddlcustomerinfo();
                },
                minLength: 0
            }).bind('focus', function () { $(this).autocomplete("search"); })
            .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

                return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<div><table><tr><td width='200px'>" + item.label + "</td>" + "<td width='110px'>" + item.val.split('~')[6] + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.val.split('~')[4] + "</td></tr></table></div>").appendTo(ul);

             };
        });
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Not clear about what do you mean by table with header. Do you mean <th />, if so, can you just add the <th /> inside table.

Comment: By addind <th> it is showing in each row@SAM

Comment: I do not understand if people can not help by giving answer then why do they down vote a question.It may be important for some one.

Comment: can you please show a working demo in jsfiddle

Comment: @sona: It is unlikely that this specific problem/question will be of use to others, however as you are asking for help, it is always best/polite to provide a complete example of code and HTML in a JSFiddle :)

Comment: Update: It actually looks like you are rendering *one table, with one row, per list item returned*. If you want a header at the top of the list you will need to reorganize at a higher level. Please provide more of your code and HTML (preferably in a JSFiddle). Failing that some screen shots would be nice.